# sudoers syntax error after adding a simple comma

Tags: sudo, sudoedit

Here is my original /etc/sudoers.d/www file:

```
Cmnd_Alias WWWCMDS = /home/xxx/shop/update.sh
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: WWWCMDS
```

I simply want to add two additional commands so I RTFM and saw that you just have to comma-separate them.

```
Cmnd_Alias WWWCMDS = /home/xxx/shop/update.sh,geoipupdate,service memcached restart
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: WWWCMDS
```

But it triggered a syntax error. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are using `visudo` to edit that file aren't you?

Comment: Yes, visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/www

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just needed to provide the full path for the two additional commands.

```
Cmnd_Alias WWWCMDS = /home/xxx/shop/update.sh,/usr/local/bin/geoipupdate,/usr/sbin/service memcached
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: WWWCMDS
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: That is fairly known behaviour. I like the cat ;) Welcome, btw +1 for the effort of documenting your own question.